# How do you prove that a function $f \in L^1( \bf R)$ and its Fourier transform cannot simultaneously be very small at infinity?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In a Research Paper it is stated that(Without any proof):

> It is well known that a function and its Fourier transform cannot simultaneously be very small at infinity?

In my First course of Harmonic Analysis I've never seen such result.Can someone explain me the precise meaning of above statement and give me some idea to prove this ?

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/hardys-uncertainty-principle/

Comment: that is, the Gauss curve is the 'extremum' with Function and Fourier transform being equal (up to...) and both indeed quite small at infinity (I don't think anyone would call a quadratic-exponential decay 'not very small'). however, you cannot have, e.g., simultaneous compact support

Comment: The Riemann Lebesgue lemma says that the Fourier transform of any $L^1$ function decays to 0 at infinity. A very unquantitative statement. (One can make more quantitative statements about the decay if $f$ is also differentiable)

Comment: Dear @Bananach What is the precise statement if $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: For fourier series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Magnitude_of_Fourier_coefficients

Comment: For fourier transformation it is a bit messier. You might know that for $L^2$ functions, the Fourier transform is still in $L^2$. If the function is differentiable though, and the derivative is in $L^2$ as well, then even $1+|\xi|^2)^{k/2}\mathcal{F}f$ is still in $L^2$ (note that the weights go to infinity at infinity)

Comment: Some user said the original question was answered by the Riemann-Lebesgue. To be clear: All expect the first two comments refer to this statement, which by now has been deleted. Of course proving decay of the transform is quite the opposite in spirit to the question that asked that simultaneous decay is NOT possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think what they mean is that the function and its Fourier transform cannot both be decreasing faster than $e^{-x^2}$ when $x \to \infty$ :

the theorem is that $e^{-\pi x^2},e^{-\pi f^2}$ is the Fourier transform couple maximizing the concentration of the energy at the origin :

$$\min \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(x)|^2 x^2 dx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\text{FT}\{h\}(f)|^2 f^2 df$$
$$\text{such that } \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(x)|^2 dx = 1$$

then the solution is $\displaystyle h(x) = c e^{-\pi x^2}$ with $|c|=1$.

(note that I didn't talk about $\displaystyle \min \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(x)|^2 x^{2k} dx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty |\text{FT}_h(f)|^2 f^{2k} df$ $\text{such that } \int_{-\infty}^\infty |h(x)|^2 dx = 1$ for $k = 2,3, \ldots$
which should be interesting too, if someone knows the solutions ? I guess it is enough to prove that the solution is an eigenfunction of the Fourier transform $h = FT\{h\}$ to get $h(x) =  e^{-\pi x^2}$ again... )